# How to assign keys to existing array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have data from a backend that I want to push to `fields` but I want to assign values to `objectKey` from the data object. Like `[{objectkey:"Normal"},{objectKey:"Network Element"}]`

main.js

```
this.fields = [{
  name: 'Ticket Number',
  objectKey: 'ticketNum',
  click: (row) => {this.rowData(row);}
},{
  name:'Ticket Opened',
  objectKey:'ticketOpened',
  click: (row) => {this.rowData(row);}
}]

data.forEach(function(item){
  item[i] = this.fields[objectKey];
}
```

data from server

```
const data = [{
    assetPriority:"Normal",
    assetType:"Network Element",
    avgChargeAmt:"1200.00"
}];
```

Comment: Your question it's unclear.  Can you edit your question to get a better understanding.

Comment: Your approach is only converting data's items to `undefined` because `this.fields[objectKey]` is not a valid way to access data from an array.  Futher, `i` variable doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Data array:**

```
const data =[{
  assetPriority: "Normal",
  assetType: "Network Element",
  avgChargeAmt:"1200.00"
}];
```

**Building an object with info from data array:**

```
const fields = {
    objectKey1: data[0].assetPriority,
    objectKey2: data[0].assetType,
    objectKey3: data[0].avgChargeAmt
};
```

**With for loop:**

```
let fieldsWithLoop = [];

for(let i = 0 ; i<data.length ; i++){
    let keys = Object.keys(data[i]);
    let objectToPush = {};

    for(let j = 0; j<keys.length;j++){
        objectToPush[keys[j]] = data[i][keys[j]];
    }

    fieldsWithLoop.push(objectToPush);
}
```

Adapt this to your system.